ksqlDB CREATE Table from STREAM is missing KEY in the json message and SINK fails
I am following the "getting started" guide.
CREATE STREAM riderLocations (profileId VARCHAR, latitude DOUBLE, longitude DOUBLE)
  WITH (kafka_topic='locations', value_format='json', partitions=1);

In my kafka server, when I check the "locations" messages it shows me the following:
KEY            | Message
some profileId | {"profileId": "some profileId", "longitude": 000, "latitude": 000}

CREATE TABLE currentLocation AS
  SELECT profileId,
         LATEST_BY_OFFSET(latitude) AS la,
         LATEST_BY_OFFSET(longitude) AS lo
  FROM riderlocations
  GROUP BY profileId
  EMIT CHANGES;

In my kafka server, when I check the "currentLocation" messages it shows me the following. If you look, its not showing the uuid in the message, like the topic before
KEY             | Message
some profileId  | {"lo": 000, "la": 000}

The problem is, when using CassandraSinkConnector it fails due to the missing/unset key.
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR cassandra_sink2 WITH (
    'connector.class' = 'io.confluent.connect.cassandra.CassandraSinkConnector',
    'cassandra.contact.points' = 'myIP',
    'cassandra.port' = '9042',
    'cassandra.security' = 'NONE',
    'topics' = 'currentLocation',
    'cassandra.keyspace' = 'locations',
    'cassandra.keyspace.create.enabled' = 'false',
    'cassandra.local.datacenter' = 'datacenter1',
    'cassandra.table' = 'CURRENTLOCATION',
    'cassandra.consistency.level' = 'LOCAL_ONE',
    'cassandra.table.manage.enabled' = 'false',
    'key.converter' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
    'value.converter' = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter',
    'key.converter.schemas.enable' = 'false',
    'value.converter.schemas.enable' = 'false',
    'confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers' = 'myIP',
    'confluent.topic.replication.factor' = '1'
);

error:

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException:
Invalid unset value for column profileId

